# WP 8.1 - NullReferenceException, unrefenced Tasks assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm writing a simple "lookup counter hero" for one of the games - more of a training rather than a development.

I have 12 tasks which are updating global variables. These tasks involve reading and deserializing a small JSON file (approx. 900 bytes), and writing some results to global variables. The interesting thing is that it runs pretty well and stable on HyperV Windows Phone emulator, while when loaded to device, it always crashes with `'System.NullReferenceException'` at line `CountersHI1.HeroImage = Counters1.IMGurl;` I believe it might be due to the fact HyperV WP is much faster at threading than physical phone is. I tried waiting for all tasks to complete but maybe I'm doing something wrong? Also, the `innerException` is confusing for me: 
`error CS0012: The type 'Task' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

I've close to no idea why does it not see my "usings" or the problem is most probably elsewhere. Any help much appreciated, below the offending code. Let me know if you need more details!

If that matters, I'm using VS 2015 Community.

```
 await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {

            Herodata hero = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Herodata>(fileContent);
            HeroInformation0.HeroImage = hero.IMGurl;
            HeroInformation0.HeroName = hero.Heroname;
            Task[] tasks = new Task[12];
            tasks[0] = new Task(() => UpdateCounteredHI1(hero.Counteredby[0]));
            tasks[1] = new Task(() => UpdateCounteredHI2(hero.Counteredby[1]));
            tasks[2] = new Task(() => UpdateCounteredHI3(hero.Counteredby[2]));
            tasks[3] = new Task(() => UpdateCounteredHI4(hero.Counteredby[3]));
            tasks[4] = new Task(() => UpdateCounteredHI5(hero.Counteredby[4]));
            tasks[5] = new Task(() => UpdateCounteredHI6(hero.Counteredby[5]));
            tasks[6] = new Task(() => UpdateCountersHI1(hero.Counters[0]));
            tasks[7] = new Task(() => UpdateCountersHI2(hero.Counters[1]));
            tasks[8] = new Task(() => UpdateCountersHI3(hero.Counters[2]));
            tasks[9] = new Task(() => UpdateCountersHI4(hero.Counters[3]));
            tasks[10] = new Task(() => UpdateCountersHI5(hero.Counters[4]));
            tasks[11] = new Task(() => UpdateCountersHI6(hero.Counters[5]));

            foreach (var task in tasks) { task.Start(); }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            CountersHI1.HeroImage = Counters1.IMGurl;
            CountersHI1.HeroName = Counters1.Heroname;
            CountersHI2.HeroImage = Counters2.IMGurl;
            CountersHI2.HeroName = Counters2.Heroname;
            CountersHI3.HeroImage = Counters3.IMGurl;
            CountersHI3.HeroName = Counters3.Heroname;
            CountersHI4.HeroImage = Counters4.IMGurl;
            CountersHI4.HeroName = Counters4.Heroname;
            CountersHI5.HeroImage = Counters5.IMGurl;
            CountersHI5.HeroName = Counters5.Heroname;
            CountersHI6.HeroImage = Counters6.IMGurl;
            CountersHI6.HeroName = Counters6.Heroname;
            CounteredHI1.HeroImage = Countered1.IMGurl;
            CounteredHI1.HeroName = Countered1.Heroname;
            CounteredHI2.HeroImage = Countered2.IMGurl;
            CounteredHI2.HeroName = Countered2.Heroname;
            CounteredHI3.HeroImage = Countered3.IMGurl;
            CounteredHI3.HeroName = Countered3.Heroname;
            CounteredHI4.HeroImage = Countered4.IMGurl;
            CounteredHI4.HeroName = Countered4.Heroname;
            CounteredHI5.HeroImage = Countered5.IMGurl;
            CounteredHI5.HeroName = Countered5.Heroname;
            CounteredHI6.HeroImage = Countered6.IMGurl;
            CounteredHI6.HeroName = Countered6.Heroname;

            HeroInformation0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            CountersTB.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            CounteredTB.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            HeroInformation0.UpdateLayout();

        });
```

Comment: General tip: Every time you find yourself numbering variables like that, you're probably doing something wrong. Create a structure to hold the instances instead of using a variable for each.

Comment: Can you simplify the code a little bit (remove/comment all tasks except one) and see if it runs on the device?

Comment: @LukkhaCoder I did as you suggested, commenting out Tasks 1..11 and the update options, it crashed at task.Start(); with the same error. Also, the same error happens on emulator. There must be something (a lot!) wrong in my code. Brian Rasmussen - I will try to find a way to simplify it (using StackPanel I guess) as this is my next step in "development project" - so far I want to get this to work as I desire :)